# Greatest common factor between polynomials

Tags: polynomials

How do I find the greatest common factor between $(x+1)^{4n+3}+x^{2n}$ and  $x^3-1$. I know that the roots for the second polynomial are 1 and $$\frac{1+i \sqrt3}{2}$$ and$$\frac{1-i \sqrt3}{2}$$.

Answer (score 2):

There is no need to leave the field of rational numbers:

We have $x^3-1=(x-1)(x^2+x+1)$. Let $f=(x+1)^{4n+3}+x^{2n}$. Clearly $f$ is co-prime to $x-1$, since $1$ is not a root. Thus the gcd is either $1$ or $x^2+x+1$, depending on whether $f = 0 \mod{x^2+x+1}$. To check that, note that $x+1=-x^2 \mod{x^2+x+1}$ and $x^3=1 \mod {x^2+x+1}$, i.e. we compute:

$$f=(-x^2)^{4n+3}+x^{2n}=x^{2n}(1-x^{6(n+1)})=x^{2n}(1-1)=0\mod{x^2+x+1}.$$

As a result, we see that the gcd is $x^2+x+1$.

Answer (score 0):

HINT:

If $x^3-1=0,$ either $x=1$ or $w,w^2$

If $f(x)=(1+x)^{4n+3}+x^{2n},$

Clearly  $f(1)\ne0$

Now as $1+w+w^2=0,$

$f(w)=(1+w)^{4n+3}+w^{2n}=(-w^2)^{4n+3}+w^{2n}=-w^{8n+6}+w^{2n}=w^{2n}(1-(w^3)^{2n+2})=0$

So, the greatest common factor will be $(x-w)(x-w^2)=?$